# Cannot Restart MongoDB 2.4.3 on Debian 6.0.7 (32-bit)

Tags: debian, mongodb

I installed MongoDB on a Debian VM using `apt-get` from the 10gen repository.  Some time after the install, I wanted to enable authentication in the configuration file, but when I ran `service mongodb restart`, it stopped and refused to start again.

I am able to reproduce this reliably: every time I run `apt-get purge mongodb-10gen; apt-get install mongodb-10gen` the server starts.  However. when I run `service mongodb start`, it says

> Starting database: mongodb **failed!**

There is nothing written to the `mongo.log` file, or any other log that I could find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited `/etc/init.d/mongodb` to remove the `--background` argument from the call to `start-stop-daemon` and got an error with a stack trace.  I can't post the full stack trace (because I can't scroll back in the terminal window to get it), but the last function call before the error was some function that has to do with getting the system language.

I had previously set `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` in order to build some ruby gems. I ran `unset LANG` and now I am able to start MongoDB.

(The interesting thing is that I then `set LANG...` again and restarted MongoDB and it still worked.)

Answer (score 1):

Did it look something like the stack trace here?

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9273

This might be a case of the Locale settings getting messed up - I have seen a logout/login fix that, or a direct setting of `LC_ALL` or similar do the same.  If you can figure out how to reproduce it reliably, then it would be worth reporting, I suspect this is actually a boost dependency rather than a MongoDB one but still worth knowing the trigger and fix for the problem.

Comment: Mine looked a little different, but it is the same as that one in that the last call before the error has `locale` in the name, which is what clued me in.  You're right that it looks from here like a boost problem.